# Expandtab converts spaces to newline character?

Tags: whitespace, tab-characters

When I enabled `expandtab` in vim by putting these in .vimrc:

```
set tw=4
set expandtab
```

Vim comverted every space typed by me to a newline character.
Like with the above settings whenever I type a new word and hit space
I get a new line.

Example:

```
What I want to type:
while (x < y):

What I get:
while
(x
<
y):
```

Comment: is there anything else in your vimrc than those 2 `set` lines? I've never seen or heard anything like this. What version are you using? What platform?

Comment: Its the textwidth line...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the textwith (`tw`) to 4. So Vim breaks the lines.

I guess you want shiftwidth:

```
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
```

Comment: That solved it.I wanted tab to be of 4 spaces.In a post I saw **tw** is for width of tab.Thanks.